# Как выполнить действие в определенное время?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Интересует, можно ли на jQuery или JS выполнять действия в назначенное время. То есть, у меня есть страница, которую нужно принудительно обновить/перезагрузить в час дня. Или же это возможно сделать с использованием на PHP / Python / сервер-сайда?

Comment: Обязательно `JavaScript`, `JQuery` или `PHP`? `cron` не подойдёт? [**Здесь**](http://kristinita.bitbucket.org/Life-hacks/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B.html) я очень подробную инструкцию составил. (Да, оно самое).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какого-либо планировщика, к которому можно обратиться через javascript в браузере нет. Обновить страницу напрямую через php тоже невозможно.

Решение в лоб: каждые 50 секунд проверять текущий час и минуту и перезагружать страницу в нужный момент. Дополнительно нужно сохранять дату последней перезагрузки, чтобы страница не перезагружалась всю минуту. Интервал в 50 секунд выбран для того, чтобы проверка срабатывала минимум один раз в минуту (setIneterval имеет погрешность).

```
var lastReloadDate;

setInterval(function () {
  var now = new Date();

  if (now.getHours() == 13 && now.getMinutes() == 0 && now.getDate() !== lastReloadDate) {
    lastReloadDate = now.getDate();
    location.reload();
  }
}, 50000);
```

Помимо этого вы можете держать постоянное соединение с сервером через long polling или WebSockets, определять нужный момент на сервере и посылать в браузер команду перезагрузки.

Разумеется, для этого страница должна быть открыта в браузере. Заставить браузер открыть какую-либо страницу с сервера невозможно. Если вы хотите, чтобы страница обновлялась *или открывалась* в нужное время, единственное решение, которое я вижу - написать небольшое расширение для браузера. Но для его работы нужен, естественное, запущенный браузер.

Comment: Зачем проверять каждые n секунд? Почему не нельзя вычислить разницу между пременем когда нужно будет перезагрузить страницу и текущем временем, и не подсавить результат в setTimeout?

Comment: @Arnial, да, это будет разумнее, не подумал про такую опимизацию.

Comment: Лучше не использовать `setInterval` из-за особенностей работы. Лучше в конце проверять условие и ставить новый `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Other, о каких особенностях работы речь?

Comment: @АлексейУколов, https://habrahabr.ru/post/138062/